# accessing array values in view

Tags: zend-form-element

```
I have the following code in zend:

 $arrErrors=array();
     if (!empty($this->post['submit']))
    {
        // Each time theres an error, add an error message to the error array
           // using the field name as the key.
          if (empty($this->post['client_name']))
          $arrErrors['client_name'] = "Please Enter Client's name as it appears in the carrier software";
    }
```

if i set $this->view->arrErrors=$arrErrors in the controller,
Can I access it as $this->arrErrors['client_name'] in the view?

Comment: or do i set it as $this->view->arrErrors['client_name']=$arrErrors['client_name'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i aplogize for  a silly question.

Here is right approach:

```
$this->view->arrErrors=arrErrors['client_name'];
```

Use the above code in the controller